# Misunderstanding of coherent states & modes expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

I misunderstand modes expansion of quantum field and coherent state expansion. Can anyone clarify differences between coherent states and modes decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mode expansion is an expansion in terms of a complete set of orthonormal modes. The orthonormality ensures that the set of modes is linearly indepenedent and so the expansion coefficients are uniquely determined. Coherent states are an *overcomplete* set of modes that are not orthonormal. You can expand things out in terms of them, but the expansion coefficients are *not* unique.